# check if character is falling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this script to check if the character is falling (I need it to set up a falling animation), but it only works when it falls from very large heights. If I jump while the character is falling, "fallen" it is not printed, while it is activated when I start to fall from greater distances. Can anyone help me or indicate another way to check if it is falling?

```
void Update()
{
  float previousHeight = 0f;
  var currentHeight = Controller.velocity.y;
  if(Controller.isGrounded) currentHeight = 0f;
  if(currentHeight < previousHeight) print("fallen");
  previousHeight = currentHeight;
}
```

Comment: `var currentHeight = Controller.velocity.y;` is some very poor naming, you are getting the velocity in the y axis, not the height at which the character is at

Comment: I changed with transform.position.y, now it works but initially it also activates when it goes up

Comment: Because previous height is local and so always is zero

Comment: how do I solve everything? do you have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in

```
float previousHeight = 0f;
```

you all the time create a new `float` with value `0` ... so making any checks against it and storing a value to it in the end is pretty useless.

---

I suspect you rather have some field already but accidentally shadowed it. It should rather be

```
// Renamed it to make my point below clear
private float previousVelocity;

private void Update()
{
    var currentVelocity = Controller.velocity.y;
    if(Controller.isGrounded) currentVelocity = 0f;
    if(currentVelocity < previousVelocity) print("fallen");
    previousVelocity = currentVelocity;
}
```

Now looking at this you will note it still makes not much sense. I renamed the variable to make my point clear: You are checking if the previous velocity is smaller than the current one. That means only you have slowed down, not necessarily that you are falling.

---

You either rather want to store and compare absolute **positions** like e.g.

```
private float previousHeight;

private void Update()
{
    var currentHeight = Controller.transform.position.y;
    if(currentHeight < previousHeight) print("fallen");
    previousHeight = transform.position.y;
}
```

or you could also simply directly use the **velocity** like

```
private void Update()
{
    var currentVelocity = Controller.velocity.y;
    if(Controller.isGrounded) currentVelocity = 0f;
    if(currentVelocity < 0f) print("fallen");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Then currenVelocity is not for me because if the character salty reaches a speed greater than zero and falling it is not detected.
The other option is almost perfect. The only flaw is that while on the ground it still signals me "fallen". I added:
 if (Controller.isGrounded) currentVelocity = 0f;
in this way it works but if you move the character over a cube it is falling despite not falling (the cube has a collider like the ground, but I think the problem is that I use Controller.isGrounded to check if it is on the ground and not always it is reliable).

Comment: I don't understand however why when the character is stopped, fallen is printed. In this way if it touches the ground I am forced to put both heights at 0, but whenstopped it must not be the result anyway 0 ..?